# Word Save As Default and Iteration

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have tried many different ways of doing this but I can't find one that works for the application.

I have a MS Word Template that will be used by another team.

This is the criteria I have been given.

- The initial file name must be 'PL' & the right most figures of a text control box.  It should also say Issue 01.
- The user must be able to chose the save location.
- If the user then opens the document at a later date and saves it should retain the name and path.
- If the user 'saves as' then it should up issue the Issue number.

The closest I can get to this working is this: -

In the top section I have this: -
`Private WithEvents App As Word.Application` and `Dim n as long`

Then in the Document New I have: -

```
Private Sub Document_New()

Set App = Word.Application

n = 0

End Sub
```

Then for the execution I have done this: -

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "PL" & Right(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Works Order Number").Item(1).Range.Text, 5) & " Issue " & Format(n, "00") & ".docx", wdFormatDocumentDefault


End Sub
```

However, this saves before the user has chosen a location.  It works but the user needs to chose the location.  So I tried this, this just does the same thing.

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

If Cancel = False Then

n = n + 1

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "PL" & Right(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Works Order Number").Item(1).Range.Text, 5) & " Issue " & Format(n, "00") & ".docx", wdFormatDocumentDefault

ElseIf Cancel = True Then

Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Any suggestions or help would very much be welcomed. I basically just want to suggest the filename which up issues with every save as.  But I cant find a way to influence that without physically saving.

Thank you in advance for your time and support.

Comment: Just intercept the saveas command by creating a Macro called FileSaveAs.  You can get the name of the file being saved using ActiveDocument.Name.

Answer (score 1):

You can repurpose ribbon controls (Save) to call your event handler first. Moreover, if required, you may cancel the default action in the event handler. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information. Repurposing ribbon controls give you a  big plus - corresponding keyboard shortcuts are handled by your code as well. So, you will be able to intercept keyboard shortcuts by the same code.

In case of Backstage UI you can hide the `SaveAs` button and add your own. Read more about the Backstage UI in the following articles:

- [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691833(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the Layout of Columns in the Office 2010 Backstage View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff628151(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thank you Eugene, this touches on to an aspect that I have not delved into before but would like to.  I will read through the material you have provided.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to learn how to use the online documentation for VBA. If you had looked up [`DocumentBeforeSave`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.documentbeforesave) you would have learned that `Cancel` is always `False` when the event is triggered. If you set it to `True` in the event handler it cancels the save.

You need to intercept the save before the dialog has been displayed, but the event is only triggered after the dialog. Because the criteria for `Save` is to use the standard functionality it is only the `FileSaveAs` you need to intercept.

Prior to the implementation of the Backstage view (the File tab) this could be solved simply by creating a routine named `FileSaveAs`. You can still do this and it will intercept the keyboard shortcut or clicking the QAT button. But it will *not intercept* the backstage commands. Only the event can do that without rebuilding the Backstage view, and the event won't work for you...

As far as intercepting the dialog to set the initial file name, that has been covered on SO before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966984/vba-word-save-as-dialog-with-initial-filename) for example.

Comment: Apologies for messing up on the `Cancel` event.  I am still fairly new to this so I can say I am lost with your advice.  I have tried the example provided and I must to be doing that wrong as it causes the dialog box to open initially and then again.

Comment: @StevenByrne - I already told you in my answer that the `DocumentBeforeSave` event isn't going to work for you and I even explained, in simple terms, why it won't work. Yet you have evidently put the `FileSaveAs` dialog code inside the event handler. Both I and @freeflow have suggested an alternative, though it has its limitations as explained above.